# Importing playwright fails with "DLL load failed while importing _greenlet"

Tags: python, playwright-python

Why does this error appear in the playwright file?

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _greenlet: The specified module could not be found.
```

Here is my code:

```python
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chrome.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FK_5SQPq6nY&list=PLYDwWPRvXB8_W56h2C1z5zrlnAlvqpJ6A&index=1")
    page.screenshot(path="demo.png")
    browser.close()
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems to be an issue of missing dependecies brought on by a version change.

I was able to get it working by installing msvc-runtime.

```
pip install msvc-runtime
```

You may need to install it in your general libraries and not inside of a virtualenv.

Comment: Installing in a virtualenv also solved the importing issue in my case. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is from greenlet version, change greenlet version to 1.1.2. I have changed and it workes