# pgAdmin 4 runtime environment error importing _greenlet

Tags: database, postgresql, backend, pgadmin

these days I was approaching PostgreSQL to implement in some of my future projects (for now I've only used MongoDB, which is NoSQL).

So, I proceeded to download the installer (for Windows) from the official site and started working with pgAdmin 4 GUI (create some tables, test some queries, etc...).

Everything seemed to be working fine, until today.

I was using pgAdmin normally, when at a certain point it randomly asked me for the password (it said session expired), I then entered it and it continued to ask me for it endlessly.

I therefore decided to uninstall and reinstall everything, in order to clean any corrupt files or folders.

Now it's even worse, after having uninstalled and reinstalled PostgreSQL, when I start pgAdmin 4, after a very long loading, a window appears with this error:

```
pgAdmin Runtime Environment
--------------------------------------------------------
Python Path: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\pgAdmin 4\python\python.exe"
Runtime Config File: "C:\Users\franc\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin\runtime_config.json"
pgAdmin Config File: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\pgAdmin 4\web\config.py"
Webapp Path: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py"
pgAdmin Command: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\pgAdmin 4\python\python.exe -s C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py"
Environment: 
  - ALLUSERSPROFILE: C:\ProgramData
  - APPDATA: C:\Users\franc\AppData\Roaming
  - CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME: \\.\pipe\crashpad_7644_DRSMLIYWYIBRTUGW
  - CHROME_RESTART: NW.js|Spiacenti, si è verificato un arresto anomalo di NW.js. Riavviarlo ora?|LEFT_TO_RIGHT
  - CommonProgramFiles: C:\Program Files\Common Files
  - CommonProgramFiles(x86): C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
  - CommonProgramW6432: C:\Program Files\Common Files
  - COMPUTERNAME: PCXXX
  - ComSpec: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
  - DriverData: C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
  - EFC_6464: 1
  - FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING: Internet Explorer
  - FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING: Default
  - HOMEDRIVE: C:
  - HOMEPATH: \Users\franc
  - IntelliJ IDEA: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.2\bin;
  - IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.1.2\bin;
  - JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20
  - LOCALAPPDATA: C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local
  - LOGONSERVER: \\PCXXX
  - NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS: 8
  - OneDrive: C:\Users\franc\OneDrive
  - OS: Windows_NT
  - Path: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\pgAdmin 4\runtime;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\franc\.console-ninja\.bin;C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\;C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\;C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\msys64\usr\bin;C:\MinGW\bin;;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.1.2\bin;;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.2\bin;;C:\Users\franc\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\heroku\bin;C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Programs\mongosh\
  - PATHEXT: .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
  - PGADMIN_INT_KEY: 11ce715e-53fb-4267-9039-fdb7f31c92a5
  - PGADMIN_INT_PORT: 50386
  - PGADMIN_SERVER_MODE: OFF
  - PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE: AMD64
  - PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER: AMD64 Family 23 Model 104 Stepping 1, AuthenticAMD
  - PROCESSOR_LEVEL: 23
  - PROCESSOR_REVISION: 6801
  - ProgramData: C:\ProgramData
  - ProgramFiles: C:\Program Files
  - ProgramFiles(x86): C:\Program Files (x86)
  - ProgramW6432: C:\Program Files
  - PSModulePath: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
  - PUBLIC: C:\Users\Public
  - SESSIONNAME: Console
  - SystemDrive: C:
  - SystemRoot: C:\Windows
  - TEMP: C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Temp
  - TMP: C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Temp
  - USERDOMAIN: PCXXX
  - USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE: PCXXX
  - USERNAME: franc
  - USERPROFILE: C:\Users\franc
  - VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\
  - windir: C:\Windows
--------------------------------------------------------

Total spawn time to start the pgAdmin4 server: 0.014 Sec
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py", line 104, in <module>

    app = create_app()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin\__init__.py", line 760, in create_app
    app.register_blueprint(module)
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\scaffold.py", line 50, in wrapper_func
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1299, in register_blueprint
    blueprint.register(self, options)
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin\tools\__init__.py", line 52, in register
    from .psql import blueprint as module
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin\tools\psql\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from eventlet.green import subprocess
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\eventlet\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from eventlet import convenience
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\eventlet\convenience.py", line 4, in <module>
    from eventlet import greenpool
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\eventlet\greenpool.py", line 4, in <module>

    from eventlet import queue
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\eventlet\queue.py", line 49, in <module>
    from eventlet.event import Event
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\eventlet\event.py", line 3, in <module>
    from eventlet import hubs
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\eventlet\hubs\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from eventlet.support import greenlets as greenlet
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\eventlet\support\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from eventlet.support import greenlets
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\eventlet\support\greenlets.py", line 3, in <module>
    import greenlet
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\greenlet\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from ._greenlet import _C_API # pylint:disable=no-name-in-module
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _greenlet: Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato.
```

I tried to search for something online, but the results were very few and poorly explained.

I still find myself with the same problem, after having tried to uninstall and reinstall the entire PostgreSQL package (and therefore also pgAdmin) many times.

Could anyone who may have encountered the same problem as me be able to help me out?

Comment: Did you read this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75675599/importing-playwright-fails-with-dll-load-failed-while-importing-greenlet

Comment: @GageHilyard yes, but it didn't work, i have to craete anothe user on windows called postgresql? idk what to do and i have to use it to follow a course on Udemy

Comment: @emeelite No you don't need anoter user on your machine. The postgres user is defined in your database. Can you open your database using psql? By default it should be user: postgres pass: postgres.
Please add to your question things you have already tried to fixing your error, like updating your greenlet module.
If you are still getting the greenlet error I suspect you may have installed greenlet for the wrong version of python.

Comment: @GageHilyard i tried everything (even pip install greenlet), i tried to install postgreSQL and then pgAdmin separately, same issues, I really don’t know what to do

Comment: @GageHilyard at the end of postgreSQL installation, it says “cannot start database server”